# Init a tuple with single quote in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I declare a `tuple` containing a quote in each side like this : `(',')`

I tried `syntax = [("'","'")]` but the output is incorrect

```
syntax[0][0]
Out[68]: "'"
```

I want the output to be just `'`

Comment: Use `print(syntax[0][0])`. What you are seeing is the `repr` not the `str` of the object. It's just a display thing

Answer (score 1):

Use `print` function to see this.

```
syntax = [("'","'")]
print(syntax[0][0]) # '
```

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
syntax = [("'","'")]
print(syntax[0][0])
```

prints out just '

if you just print out syntax[0] you will get ("'", "'") but thats the only way it will work as you cant just have ' as that is not valid it has to be a string there fore in the tuple its represented in the double quotes